# How to find an average of a certain column in Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, average

Using: Access 2003

I have a table with atleast 250 data entries. My goal is to find the average of some of the columns (for example average of the TotalNumSuverys column). A simple mathemtical equation like SUM / (Number of survery takers) wont work because depending on the specific column, the total number of entries differ.

How can I achieve the average of a column?

(I have tried the "Avg" aggregate in the Query View and found that it averages the row not the column.)

Is there any SQL that would allow to do something like a "ForEach loop"?

--I'm very new at this, sorry!

Comment: `SELECT Avg(t.ANumber) AS AvgOfANumber
FROM Table t` gives an average of the column, ANumber. What do you want? Please include sample data.

Answer (score 2):

The `Avg()` function gives you the average (arithmetic mean) of only the non-Null values in the column.  Or, in your example, a Null value would be excluded from both "SUM" and "Number of survery takers".

Access' query designer can be confusing at first (as best I recall).  Maybe it would make more sense to you if you switch to SQL View and type in an example statement using this pattern ...

```
SELECT Avg(MyColumn) AS AvgOfMyColumn
FROM MyTable;
```

... substituting your column name for MyColumn and your table name for MyTable.  Then run the query (Datasheet View) to see what it gives you.  Then you can switch back to Design View to see how it is presented there.

Other aggregate functions, not just `Avg()`, also ignore Null values.  For example, `Count(MyColumn)` will give you the number of rows where MyColumn is not Null.  [If you wanted a count of all rows regardless of whether any individual columns contain Null, use `Count(*)`]  And `Sum(MyColumn)` will add only the non-Null MyColumn values.

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason the `Avg()` does not work for you, you can use the basic way :

```
Dim rSet As DAO.Recordset, cnt As Integer, sum As Integer, avg As Variant
rSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("Select Sum(MyColumn), Count(MyKey) from MyTable")
sum  = rSet.Fiels(0)
cnt  = rSet.Fiels(1)
avg = sum/cnt
MsgBox "The average is " & avg
```